# How does SAS retain the value from a previous row without the 'retain' statement?

Tags: sas

I am working on [this example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect059.htm) which explains how to fit a standard Cox model with `proc mcmc` in `SAS 9.3`.

For the first row in the data (`ind=1`), `S=exp(bZ)` is computed along with other quantities. It is important to note that **`S` is a new variable** constructed from the columns of the original data set.

For the second row (`1 < in < &N`), `S` is incremented: `S = S + exp(bZ)`.

**Question:** How does SAS retain the value of `S` from the previous row? I would have expected a `retain` statement or something equivalent...

---

**Relevant part of the code:**

```
if ind = 1 then do;        /* first observation         */
  S = exp(bZ);
  l = vstatus * bZ;
  v = vstatus;
 end;
 else if (1 < ind < &N) then do;
  if (lag1(time) ne time) then do;
     l = vstatus * bZ;
     l = l - v * log(S);  /* correct the loglike value   */
     v = vstatus;         /* reset v count value         */
     S = S + exp(bZ);
  end;
  else do;                /* still a tie                 */
     l = vstatus * bZ;
     S = S + exp(bZ);
     v = v + vstatus;     /* add # of nonsensored values */
  end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `lag1()` function that is retaining values but be careful!

The `lag()` function will remember the value *from the previous time it was executed*, not the previous row!  Because your lag function only gets executed when the first `if` condition is not true, then there may be hard to debug problems arising from this.

I suggest changing to use a `retain` statement which are more explicit and easier to debug.  If you do choose to keep using the `lag1()` function and you are having problems with the code I suggest you move it out of the conditional logic so your code looks like this:

```
prev_time = lag1(time);
if ind = 1 then do;        /* first observation         */
  S = exp(bZ);
  l = vstatus * bZ;
  v = vstatus;
 end;
 else if (1 < ind < &N) then do;
  if prev_time ne time then do;
     l = vstatus * bZ;
     l = l - v * log(S);  /* correct the loglike value   */
     v = vstatus;         /* reset v count value         */
     S = S + exp(bZ);
  end;
  else do;                /* still a tie                 */
     l = vstatus * bZ;
     S = S + exp(bZ);
     v = v + vstatus;     /* add # of nonsensored values */
  end;
 end;
```

BTW - there's `lag(), lag1(), lag2(), lag3(), etc....` functions that also exist.

Comment: I agree with your warning about 'lag'. But still, even in the 'else do loop' the value of S is retained from the previous row and incremented...

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset and results?

Comment: Well, the data set is available here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect046.htm, and the code which produces the result is here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect059.htm ; thanks!

Comment: Oops!  Great thanks - didn't see that.  I should have read the question more thoroughly.  =|

Comment: Your post together with the following sentense from SAS help answer my question: "The LAG function returns values of a variable from a queue. As PROC MCMC steps through the data set, the LAG function queues each data set variable, and you have access to the current value **as well as to all previous values of any variable**."

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry this is not the answer, just note what's said at http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mcmc_sect017.htm

> Most of the programming statements that can be used in the DATA step
>   can also be used in PROC MCMC.

and

> For the most part, the SAS programming statements work the same as
>   they do in the DATA step, as documented in SAS Language Reference:
>   Concepts. However, there are several differences...

So my impression is the syntax inside `BEGINCNST` and `ENDCNST` blocks is almost same as in datastep, but some of internal workings are different, which is probably the case regarding retaining of computed values (?). So probably this doesn't work same as in datastep PDV (program data vector).